# asp.net mvc disable ajax cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, jquery

I load list of data by using ajax and partial view(ascx)
But I have a problem: my response is cached.
I try to write Responce.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) in ascx file but it is not helped

In ASP.NET WebForms I've solved this by writing Responce.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) in codebehind.
So I'd like to know where can I write Responce.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) to disable cache.

Comment: it shouldn't be cached unless you explicitly tell it so on the controller action directive. maybe it's the browser? i have heard of ie caching ajax gets (but not posts).

Comment: yes page is cached by browser. But it is easy to solve by using SetExpires. How can I set SetExpires with MVC?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use jQuery?

```
$.ajax({
 cache:false,
 ...
});
```

or Controller / Action set OutputCacheAttribute.

[OutputCacheAttribute Class (System.Web.Mvc)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.aspx)

Comment: How exactly OutputCacheAttribute will help to disable cache??

Comment: This attribute control http response header(cache-control,expires etc).

Comment: I meant it would be good here to give an code example how to use OutputCacheAttribute for that:
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]

Answer (score 0):

You should be using ajax POST to controller method that returns JsonResult if you want to load data from server asynchronously.

Comment: If you are *getting* data, you should *not* be using POST. Look on HTTP methods as CRUD: Post = Create, Get = Read, Put = Update, Delete = Delete

Comment: Arve's comment is not correct. ASP.Net MVC doesn't support REST operations, and it is quite acceptable to use a POST method to retrieve data based on a parameter.