# How to read a hidden field value in MVC3 view within the code block (" @() etc. ") (tried a lot of things but cant put in place)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, .net-4.0

I Have a hidden field that contains a value and my code block within view (within @{} ) requires the same . I have tried a lot of formats trying to use jquery with @: etc. but non of them work.

so basically if i have a hidden field with ID="aField" having a value, I will require the value of it somehow on to my say a string variable.

```
@{ string hiddenValue = //Value from that hidden field }
```

Thanks,
Anand

**UPDATE :**

The value onto hidden field is populated on some client actions using Jquery and is required before form submit. Hence I am not using view bag . Am i mistaken or missing something ?

hence i am looking for a way to may be if possible use jquery to read back the updated value and use it .

tried a lot to include jquery within the above shown code block to get the value but always end up in errors.

**UPDATE 2:**

Implemented the suggestion by Shoib (thanks for that) to use Ajax and update the same in viewbag and use it for my requirement, also with break points I see that ViewBag has updated value that I am using in my form.

the next thing i am stumbled up is , on browser still i do not see the value selected . it just displayes old value. Is my update lost during rendering / is it just rendering old HTML ? Any help appreciated

below is my script. server side i just update ViewBAg property with this value that works confirmed.

```
  function setHiddenFieldValue(buttonEditClicked)
    {



    $('#contactIdHiddenFld').val("");

    $('#contactIdHiddenFld').val(buttonEditClicked.title) ;
    alert($('#contactIdHiddenFld').val());


    $.ajax({         
        url: "@Url.Action("SetPartnerProfileContactID", "PartnerManagement")",         
        data: {partnerContactID: $("#contactIdHiddenFld").val()},         
        dataType: 'html', 
        cache: false,        
        type: "POST",         
        error: function() {             
            alert("An error occurred.");         
        },         
        success: function(result) {             
    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.parse('EditContactForm');
    Sys.Mvc.FormContext._Application_Load();

          var windowElement = $('#EditContactWindow');         
      windowElement.data('tWindow').center().open();

        }     
    });
```

Also here is a snippet of the form .

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetProfile", "PeopleManagement", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "EditContactForm" }))
{
    <p class="note">
        Please Enter the contact details below</p>


    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="EditContactsTable">

        @{                
            string toCheck = ViewBag.ContactIDToEdit;
            int count = (from n in Model.PartnerDetails.Contacts where n.PrimaryContactId==toCheck select n).Count();

         }

        <tr>
            <td class="table_label_cell" width="20%" >
                <font color="red">*</font><label for="firstname">@ViewResources.PartnerManagement.GetPartnerProfile.FirstName :</label>
            </td>
            <td class="table_value_cell" width="40%">                   
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PartnerDetails.Contacts[count].PrimaryContacts.FirstName)

            </td>
            <td class="table_value_cell" width="40%">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.PartnerDetails.Contacts[count].PrimaryContacts.FirstName)
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="table_label_cell" width="20%">
                <font color="red">*</font><label for="lastname">@ViewResources.PartnerManagement.GetPartnerProfile.LastName :</label>
            </td>
            <td class="table_value_cell" width="40%">
                 @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PartnerDetails.Contacts[count].PrimaryContacts.LastName)
            </td>
            <td class="table_value_cell" width="40%">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(e => e.PartnerDetails.Contacts[count].PrimaryContacts.LastName)
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Comment: Can you please put some code/html which you are using?

Comment: have to tried storing hidden field value in viewbag???? from controller action? this way you can access it in view..

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh , That does not help me. Just added some updates on to my question. Regret not providing more clarity initially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
            ViewBag.hfMyField = Request.Form["hfMyField"];
            return View();
        }
```

this way you can access it in view.

```
 <h4>@ViewBag.hfMyField</h4>
```

for more details on viewbag and other options:
http://rachelappel.com/when-to-use-viewbag-viewdata-or-tempdata-in-asp.net-mvc-3-applications

Regards.

Comment: the value is populated on some client actions and is required before form submit. I have used jquery to store value onto this hiddenfield. later on require this value for the above mentioned operation

Comment: seems like you are confused in two.. do you want to do some action using client script(javascript) or you want to access the value in server code? if you have set the value on client side then you can only access that value in server code in subsequent postback..

Comment: this is the asp.net mvc request life cycle.. http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/03/18/asp-net-mvc-in-depth-the-life-of-an-asp-net-mvc-request.aspx render view is the last method called... and anything modified after that using some client script can only be accessible on another subsequent request..

Comment: Hmmm, Ok ,the reason I am kind of sticking to this is.

I have a list in my model , on the edit form I would like to edit only one of the items in that list based on which the user chose to edit (clicking a link against that entry opening a model window) . the item to be edited is stored in hidden field and then later I just populate these values in form using TextBoxFor(m => m.List[ThatItemCountfromHiddenField].PropertyName  .

Comment: alright.. have you tried doing this using ajax? in ajax you can post some control's data(hf value) to  controller action and in return you can get markup of your choice.. try opening modal window using jquery UI and use ajax to inject html in it using some partial view.

Comment: Great ! thanks.. I was just so stressed out , dint think of that. I am guessing that will do. 

thanks

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh : I have  implemented your suggestion and able to read the value thru viewbag and then using in " TextBoxFor(m => m.List[ThatItemCountfromHiddenField].PropertyName   " . the count is updated. (debugged with break point to see updated value).

but the issue i am facing is that on browser i still see just the old from collection . I am sensing that thought the HTML is updated the one rendered on the browser is still old. tries cache:false and Outputcaching false in controller. any thoughts please ?

Comment: have you tried disabling ajax cache http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4067486/asp-net-mvc-disable-ajax-cache.

Comment: Yes I did and also tried "[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Duration = 0, VaryByParam = "*")]" onto my controller code

"
 public ActionResult SetPartnerProfileContactID(string partnerContactID)
        {
            ViewBag.ContactIDToEdit = partnerContactID;
...  return PartialView("GetPartnerContactsPartial", partnerDetailsViewModel);
}
"

Comment: give me snap of how you call the action using jquery

Comment: Hi , snippet below, 

 $.ajax({         
        url: "@Url.Action("SetPartnerProfileContactID", "PartnerManagement")",         
        data: {partnerContactID: $("#contactIdHiddenFld").val()},         
        dataType: 'html', 
        cache: false,        
        type: "POST",        ...


I just added the complete script as 'update 2 ' in my post above

Comment: in 'success: function(result) {' callback, you haven't used 'result' object that contain the updates html markup.

Comment: Since i have refreshed the partial view, I am assuming that the html is again wholly generated and i do not need to update the html again .

is My assumption wrong ? Sorry for the to & fro comments but i m pretty new to MVC and exploring the options.

Do we need to update html, as In my case I am just doing ajax call to get the selected hiddenfield value in viewbag to access the property

Comment: what does result object contains? some ID or html?

Comment: it contains an html, also i just tried "   $('#EditContactForm').html(result);  " but that throws error saying "unexpected call to method or property access". the form above is the form i want to get updated

Comment: I just corrected the above error, but then after binding result to a div containing my partial view, I am still getting the not updated data. I think the variable in  partial view is getting reset. as I am getting only Details.Contacts[0].PrimaryContacts.FirstName . its always 0 though i update value from view bag and also the result contains Details.Contacts[1].PrimaryContacts.FirstName

Answer (score 0):

Read the value from the controller and put it in the ViewModel your page needs.